# Issue with adding common code as git submodule: "already exists in the index"

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want to add some git submodules.
I've received two projects sharing some common code. The shared code was just copied into the two projects. I created a separate git repo for the common code and removed it from the projects with the plan to add it as a `git` submodule.

I used the path option of git submodule add to specify the folder:

```
git submodule add url_to_repo projectfolder
```

but then got the error:

```
'projectfolder' already exists in the index"
```

This is the desired structure of my repository:

```
repo
|-- projectfolder
    |-- folder with common code
```

It is possible to add the `git` submodule directly in the repo, or into a new folder there, but not in the project folder. The problem is that it really need to be in the project folder..
What can I do about this and what have I misunderstood about the path option of git submodule add?

Comment: What do you get if you do `git ls-files --stage projectfolder`?

Comment: I get a list with all content starting with 100644.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696919/cant-add-existing-git-repository-into-new-repository/37336838#37336838

Comment: for me doing a `git rm` on the existing folder helped :|

Answer (score 499):

*I'm afraid there's not enough information in your question to be certain about what's going on, since you haven't replied to my follow-up question, but this may be of help in any case.*

That error means that `projectfolder` is already staged ("already exists in the index").  To find out what's going on here, try to list everything in the index under that folder with:

```
git ls-files --stage projectfolder
```

The first column of that output will tell you what type of object is in the index at `projectfolder`.  (These look like Unix filemodes, but have special meanings in git.)

I suspect that you will see something like:

```
160000 d00cf29f23627fc54eb992dde6a79112677cd86c 0   projectfolder
```

(i.e. a line beginning with `160000`), in which case the repository in `projectfolder` has already been added as a "gitlink".  If it doesn't appear in the output of `git submodule`, and you want to re-add it as a submodule, you can do:

```
git rm --cached projectfolder
```

... to unstage it, and then:

```
git submodule add url_to_repo projectfolder
```

... to add the repository as a submodule.

However, it's also possible that you will see many blobs listed (with file modes `100644` and `100755`), which would suggest to me that you didn't properly unstage the files in `projectfolder` before copying the new repository into place.  If that's the case, you can do the following to unstage all of those files:

```
git rm -r --cached projectfolder
```

... and then add the submodule with:

```
git submodule add url_to_repo projectfolder
```

Comment: Thank Mark for your detailed answer. I did a "git rm -r --cached projectfolder" and tried to att the submodule again. However this time I get the error rmessage "'projectfolder' already exists and is not a valid git repo".

Comment: @Vanja: That indicates that `projectfolder` didn't contain a `.git` directory.  It sounded from your question as if you'd created the new repository for `projectfolder` elsewhere, and copied it into place, but clearly that wasn't the case.  You'd need to move the existing `projectfolder` out of the way, and then copy the new repository (complete with its `.git` directory) into place before adding as a submodule.  Or, if you've already pushed it to the repository represented by `url_to_repo`, you could just move `projectfolder` out of the way and then add the submodule from that URL.

Comment: This is what I did, which is 3 step process                                                    STEP 1: git rm -r --cached src/test/resources/  , 
STEP 2: removed existing resources directory to some other place , 
STEP 3: git submodule add add url_to_repo src/test/resources

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out when I had tried to add another repo in a hurry and did it the wrong way (git clone inside a repo, instead of git submodule add).  On my other machine, it appeared to be a submodule, but no .gitmodules file was ever created.  The above steps set me on the path to fixing the issue.  Much obliged!

Comment: `projectfolder` shouldn't be a part of the existing parent repo, it would be created while running `git submodule add`.

Answer (score 129):

You need to remove your submodule git repository (projectfolder in this case) first for git path.

```
rm -rf projectfolder

git rm -r projectfolder
```

and then add submodule

```
git submodule add <git_submodule_repository> projectfolder
```

Comment: `git submodule add --force <git_submodule_repository>` worked for me to keep the same submodule name

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't have to add in the project folder, I just changed into the subdirectory and clones from there.

Comment: You'r a genius !

Comment: Simple but its works. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to push submodule before rm command!

Answer (score 76):

Removing submodule manually involves number of steps and this worked for me.

Assuming you are in the project root directory and sample git module name is "c3-pro-ios-framework"

**Remove the files associated to the submodule**

```
rm -rf .git/modules/c3-pro-ios-framework/
```

**Remove any references to submodule in config**

```
vim .git/config
```

[image]

**Remove .gitmodules**

```
rm -rf .gitmodules
```

**Remove it from the cache without the "git"**

```
git rm --cached c3-pro-ios-framework
```

**Add submodule**

```
git submodule add https://github.com/chb/c3-pro-ios-framework.git
```

Answer (score 35):

I had the same problem and after hours of looking found the answer.

The error I was getting was a little different: `<path> already exists and is not a valid git repo` (and added here for SEO value)

The solution is to NOT create the directory that will house the submodule. The directory will be created as part of the `git submodule add` command.

Also, the  argument is expected to be relative to the parent-repo root, not your working directory, so watch out for that.

Solution for the example above:

1. It IS okay to have your parent repo already cloned.
2. Make sure the `common_code` directory does **not** exist.
3. `cd Repo`
4. `git submodule add git://url_to_repo projectfolder/common_code/` (*Note the required trailing slash.*)
5. Sanity restored.

I hope this helps someone, as there is very little information to be found elsewhere about this.

Comment: Step 4 should begin `git submodule add`, and the trailing slash isn't required.

Comment: Fixed the typo. I have retested it, and the trailing slash has made a difference for me. I'm using zsh if that has any effect.

Comment: This solved my problem (creating the directory with the add submodule commnand), thank you!

Comment: Thank you so so so much, this was my problem ... so relative path from inside your module to a folder including trailing slash !!! This solved it, thx. 
so for me the command looked like this for gitbash:

`git submodule add -b master "git@bitbucket.org:remote_repo.git" "mytools/src/project/grpc/protos/" `

Comment: "Sanity restored." Amen

Answer (score 24):

if there exists a folder named `x` under git control, you want add a same name submodule , you should **delete folder `x` and commit it first**.

Updated by @ujjwal-singh:

Committing is not needed, staging suffices.. `git add` / `git rm -r`

Comment: The committing was what I missed. Short answer, but correct one!

Comment: Committing is not needed, staging suffices.. `git add` / `gir rm -r`

Comment: Thanks. I moved my existing folder (an unrecognised subrepository) out of the master repo. I committed all changes to the master repo. Then I moved the subrepository back into it and was able to add it after that, using SourceTree.

Answer (score 5):

Just to clarify in human language what the error is trying to tell you:

You cannot create a repository in this folder which already tracked in the main repository.

For example: You have a theme folder called `AwesomeTheme` that's a dedicated repository, you try do dump it directly into your main repository like `git submodule add sites/themes` and you get this `"AwesomeTheme" index already exists`.

You just need to make sure there isn't already a `sites/themes/AwesomeTheme` in the main repository's version tracking so the submodule can be created there.

So to fix, in your main repository if you have an empty `sites/theme/AwesomeTheme` directory then remove it. If you have already made commits with the `sites/theme/AwesomeTheme` directory in your main repository you need to purge all history of it with a command like this:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \
              'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch sites/theme/AwesomeTheme'     HEAD
```

Now you can run `git submodule add git@AwesomeTheme.repowhateverurlthing sites/themes/AwesomeTheme`

Since the main repository has never seen anything (a.k.a index'd) in `sites/themes/AwesomeTheme` before, it can now create it.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by doing it the other way around. Starting with an empty repo, adding the submodule in a new folder called "projectfolder/common_code". After that it was possible to add the project code in projectfolder. The details are shown below.

In an empty repo type:

```
git submodule add url_to_repo projectfolder/common_code
```

That will create the desired folder structure:

```
repo
|-- projectfolder
    |-- common_code
```

It is now possible to add more submodules, and the project code can be added to projectfolder.

I can't yet say why it worked this way around and not the other.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the repository folder. Delete relevant submodules from .gitmodules. Select show hidden files. Go to .git folder, delete the submodules from module folder and config.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu then remember to delete files from trash also.

In my Case i moved the files to trash.

Comment: Unbelievable, that was my problem indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is any useful, though I had the same problem when trying to commit my files from within IntelliJ 15. In the end, I opened SourceTree and in there I could simply commit the file. Problem solved. No need to issue any fancy git commands. Just mentioning it in case anyone has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the .git file is missing in the target path. It happend to me after I executed `git clean -f -d`.

I had to delete all target folders showing in the message and then executing `git submodule update --remote`

Comment: Careful with the `git clean -f -d` ! Ensure all files are backuped first !!!

Comment: I never mentioned that you should execute `git clean -f -d`

Answer (score -31):

In your git dir, suppose you have sync all changes.

```
rm -rf .git 

rm -rf .gitmodules
```

Then do:

```
git init
git submodule add url_to_repo projectfolder
```

Comment: this will delete the whole history of the project !