# Git submodule add: "a git directory is found locally" issue

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm actually trying to learn how to use git, including the `git submodule` subcommands.
I already set up a server on which I can host, push and pull git repositories by using SSH.
I created a main git repository "Travail" on this server in which I would like to put all my projects as submodules.

In my Travail repository, I already added a project of mine as a submodule at `tools/libft`:
I'm able to develop this submodule, to push and to pull it.

But when I try to add another submodule (named fdf, from fdf.git on my server), I get the following issue :

```
git submodule add ssh://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX/opt/git/fdf.git projets/fdf
```

> A git directory for 'projets/fdf' is found locally with remote(s):
>         origin    ssh://git@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX/opt/git/fdf.git
>       If you want to reuse this local git directory instead of cloning again from
>         ssh://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX/opt/git/fdf.git
>       use the '--force' option. If the local git directory is not the correct repo 
>       or you are unsure what this means choose another name with the '--name' option.

There is actually no subdirectory in `projets/`

I read on another thread that I should use `git submodule sync` or edit the .gitmodules file in which the URL to my submodule's origin repository could have changed.

But my .gitmodules file only contains the information about my first submodule (tools/libft), not about projets/fdf :

```
[submodule "tools/libft"]
    path = tools/libft
    url = ssh://git@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX/opt/git/libft.git
```

As a French student I could have missed something in the English documentation I have, but I searched and I really don't understand why I get this issue.

I would be glad if I would get a solution but just an explanation would be helpful too.

Comment: A small correction: it's 'repository', not 'depository'.  Not really an answer, but if the projects are independent of each other it would be better for each project to have its own repo instead of submodules.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected.
I know but I would like to gather all my work in the same repo but as separate projects.
It is a choice to keep my whole work updated when I go from home to my school and vice versa (and to learn how to use these tools, I'm curious ;) )

Comment: Well, curiosity is always a good reason!  :)  That is strange.  Are you sure you haven't added the submodule before?

Comment: Not in Travail/, and I have no problème to clone fdf.git in ~/ .
In Travail/ I find no traces of fdf.
just libft :/

Comment: Oh wait, I looked in `/Travail/.git/modules/projets/` and I found a `fdf` directory. This seems to not be in the working tree but in older commits. Could it generate the issue?

Comment: Yes, possibly. So it was committed in the main project?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898278/issue-with-adding-common-code-as-git-submodule-already-exists-in-the-index/37336854#37336854

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace a git submodule with another repo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404704/how-do-i-replace-a-git-submodule-with-another-repo)

Answer (score 854, accepted):

I came to this SO post trying to add a submodule with the same path as a submodule that I recently deleted.

This is what ultimately worked for me ([this article helped out a lot](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/03/git-submodules-workflows-tips/)):

If you haven't already run
`git rm --cached path_to_submodule` (no trailing slash) as well as
`rm -rf path_to_submodule`

Then:

1. Delete the relevant lines from the `.gitmodules` file. e.g. delete these:

```
[submodule "path_to_submodule"]
        path = path_to_submodule
        url = https://github.com/path_to_submodule
```

2. Delete the relevant section from .git/config. e.g. delete these:

```
[submodule "path_to_submodule"]
        url = https://github.com/path_to_submodule
```

3. `rm -rf .git/modules/path_to_submodule`

Then, you can finally:

`git submodule add https://github.com/path_to_submodule`

Comment: Make sure your `submodule` directory is not in your `.gitignore`

Comment: I had to remove `.git/modules/module_name` to get it working

Comment: In my case I also had to close and open a new bash window, something was stored in memory!

Comment: @jbmilgrom why `git rm --cached path_to_submodule`? I would `git rm` without `cached`.

Comment: This looks like a bug in git, because you can't solve it within `git` command scope, you will have to call `rm ./git/modules/path`, which is especially painful in a CI environment. And even locally, you have to do this every time you checkout between those branches. Is there any approach that can solve this within `git` command? something like parameter with `--no-keep-directory` that will clean `.git/modules/path/to/module`?

Comment: This is why I hate git..., why not have a git submodule remove command?

Answer (score 92):

i tried jbmilgrom's solution, specifically i tried `git rm --cache` and that didn't work for me either as the directory/submodule wasn't there.  What worked for me was:

1. `rm -rf .git/modules/blah`
2. `git submodule add git://path.to.new`

I did this after trying `--force` within the `git submodule` commands and `rm` all the other directories, pushes to master etc... the directory didn't exist and there was no reason for the cache. Turns out in `.git/modules` that is where this error was lying.

Comment: This is the solution I used. The others did not work for me because the directory wasn't there on the disk, because git actually failed to clone the submodule properly (the remote repo had no branches, therefore git could not clone it. Or something.)

Answer (score 21):

If you already deleted the submodule directory, like I did, follow the rest of jbmilgrom's instructions. The key is `rm -rf .git/modules/path_to_submodule` but go ahead and **backup your whole parent repo directory first**.

If you only had one submodule just delete `.gitmodules`

Answer (score 17):

You may have deleted your `'projets/fdf'` from disk, but your Git repository still has it. Use `git rm -rf projets/fdf` to remove it from Git, then commit the changes. After that you'll be able to add this folder as a submodule.

Comment: It worked :) Thank you.

I think I actually made this mistake.

Comment: I was searching a `git submodule rm` command, but there is no such command? isn't it?

Comment: @vmonteco No, there isn't. But you can use [this workflow](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial#Removal) or, for example, `git delete-submodule` command from [`git-extras`](https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras) package by TJ Holowaychuk.

Comment: @vmonteco Also, it's a good practice in general to accept the right answer, so the other people could see it right away. ;)

Comment: That's right ;) But I didn't yet know how to do (it was my first question)

Thanks for the explanations!

Comment: I get told the directory doesn't exist when I do this. Seems it both exists and doesn't :/

Comment: Same problem here, directory doesn't exists, can't git rm -rf it and can't add new submodule

Comment: @sparklos Did you figure this out? I'm dealing with the same problem

Comment: @tom-mcfarlin In the end, Imanually removed lines from .gitmodule and a folder from .git/modules, then it let me add a new submodule. Maybe there's better way to do this, but I was running out of time. If you gonna go this way, I recommend you make a good backup and please don't blame me, if it goes wrong for you. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, I found on another post to remove the folder from .git/modules and that worked for me. Makes sense as that's what the error said was the conflict... I just was unaware of that folder

Comment: @NathanHornby @Sparklos @TomMcFarlin -- In more recent versions of git, you will find that git-submodule adds a directory in .git folder. For example, if you are in directory `/tmp/repo`, then run `git submodule add ../otherrepo.git`, then you will see that `/tmp/repo/.git/modules/otherrepo` folder exists. That is what the problem was for me. I manually deleted that folder from .git, and everything worked.

Comment: This isn't the correct answer. It doesn't remove the submodule completely. The answer by @jbmilgrom coveres the problem in detail.

Answer (score 10):

These two commands works for me.

```
rm path/to/submodule -rf
rm .git/modules/path/to/module -rf
```

Comment: This. It seems there are two ways for submodules to be created. In one of them, the subfolder will only have a single .git file that simply points to a directory in the superproject, starting with `.git/modules/`. In there is a folder that stores the repository for the submodule. Deleting that repository fixed the issue for me, while the accepted answer didn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this while cloning your submodule:

git submodule add --name *submodule_name* *submodule path*

This will add your submodule into your project and will be added as a structure under `.gitmodules` file.

And then if you don't want the older one you can remove it from `.gitmodules` structure and delete the submodule folder from the project.

Answer (score 1):

I added an empty submodule (no files, branches) and tried the commands in the other answers to delete it.

However, while the files were deleted, the local git directory remained, so I had to go to the `.git` folder and manually delete the submodule from `.git/modules/SUBMODULE-PATH`, which finally resolved this error and got `git submodule add` to work.

The `.git` folder is hidden. On Windows, you can enable "Hidden items" under View in File Explorer and then access it from the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, and this did the trick for me:

```bash
# force register the submodule in .gitmodules
git submodule add -f <name> <path>

# force git to update cached submodule configs
git submodule sync --recursive
```

From the docs:

> sync [--recursive] [--] [...]
>
> Synchronizes submodules' remote URL configuration setting to the value specified in .gitmodules. It
> will only affect those submodules which already have a URL entry in
> .git/config (that is the case when they are initialized or freshly
> added). This is useful when submodule URLs change upstream and you
> need to update your local repositories accordingly.

The issue is that, despite your `.gitmodules` file being updated, the underlying config `.git/modules/tools/libft` is still pointed at the old submodule URL.

The other solutions recommending you `rm -rf .git/modules/<repo>` are just deleting the config that `git submodule sync` updates for you.