# Git submodule add: “a git directory is found locally” issue

Tags: git, git-submodules

Hi one follow up question to the question discussed in [Git submodule add: “a git directory is found locally” issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20929336/git-submodule-add-a-git-directory-is-found-locally-issue/23109765?noredirect=1)

I have a lot of such submodule directories(not sure how many)

Is it somehow possible to initialize all the submoudules as listed in .gitmodules and force pull all of them.

Additionally I would like to reset all of the submodules and discard any changes locally present.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it somehow possible to initialize all the submoudules as listed in .gitmodules and force pull all of them.

You could delete all the submodule directories and then re-run `git submodule update`.  Maybe like this:

```
git config -f .gitmodules --list | 
  awk -F= '$1 ~ /.path$/ {print $2}' | 
  xargs rm -rf
```

This uses `git config` to list the configuration in `.gitmodules`, which produces output like this:

```
submodule.common.path=common
submodule.common.url=https://github.com/purpleidea/puppet-common.git
```

We use `awk` to extract the path information, and then pass that to `xargs` to delete all the submodule directories.  Running `submodule update` will then re-populate those directories:

```
$ git submodule update
Submodule path 'common': checked out '2c0ed2844c606fd806bde0c02e47e79c88fab4a9'
```

> Additionally I would like to reset all of the submodules and discard any changes locally present.

Because we're deleting and re-cloning the submodules, this will also discard any local changes.