# git submodule add error: does not have a commit checked out

Tags: git, bitbucket

I create a new git repository with the help of bitbucket called *confusionmatrix*. Now, I'm trying in another git repository (called *workspace*) add the *confusionmatrix* repository as submodule like this:

```
git submodule add https://....@bitbucket.org/..../confusionmatrix.git
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> 'confusionmatrix' does not have a commit checked out

I already made this with other git repositories to the same repository "workspace" and worked well.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you just created an *empty* Git repository on BitBucket, try and make sure to make at least one commit (or push one commit) to it.

Do that *before* referencing that repository as a submodule in your second local repository.

Answer (score 118):

As an FYI, the same message is shown if by accident you already have a .git folder in any of the subfolder under the folder you are trying to add. If that's the case, then delete the git subfolder and if any .vs file is there, delete that too. That was my case and I had the same error message.

Comment: Hey Thanks ! Removing the internal git folder worked for me.

Comment: This may happen as result of a previously failed `git submodule add` (in my case, the submodule was not populated yet and had not any commit). Then just delete the entire directory of the submodule (including the `.git` file).

Comment: Following this, I ended up with this error message "A git directory for '[submodule-name]' is found locally with remote(s):" [...] If you want to reuse this use the --force option. I Had to use `rm -rf .git/modules/[submodule-name]` credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/38420557/2832282

Comment: +1 This was the error for me as well. Visual Studio automatically create a .git folder, even though it was already part of a repo. This answer is what made me check for the folder.

Comment: In my case i had a .git folder under venv.  I removed it and it works.

Answer (score 60):

1. Find leftover `.git` folder in some sub directories (the directory is shown in the error msg!)

```
find ./ -name '.git'
```

2. Delete it (**make sure to have the right folder!!!**)

```
rm -r yourfolder/.git/
```

3. try again

Comment: On the submodule, if you initialize git then you may have this problem. I accidentally had done the same, I followed the above steps and it worked. Thanks @giesOr

Answer (score 12):

In my case subfolder is containing .git folder.

Check if any subfolder contains '.git' folder. Delete that ".git" folder and it will work.

OR another way is

In git-shell Run

```
rm -rf .git
```

Comment: Run  "rm -rf .git" in git-shell, works like a charm for me

Answer (score 8):

I had another .git folder in subdirectory, I did pull from repository before initializing it, after deleting that repository, `git add .` worked

Comment: I had the same issue. My framework (Nest.js) automatically created a `.git` folder in the project's subdirectory. I had to remove before I could commit the subdirectory.

Answer (score 2):

```
git commit -m "if you have something you want to Keep comment"
```

delete branch manually with all files on your disc

```
git clone https://WhereMyOriginIs" MyLocalFolderName
```

Answer (score 2):

its due to a inner git project available inside your submodules.
try searching for .git folder and remove that.

Answer (score 2):

```
error: '[route]' does not have a commit checked out
fatal: adding files failed
```

This error may be generated because a `.git` file is found on the route than can not be `add`

If you navigate to the [route] and execute `git status` and recieve the next error

```
fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '[route]'
```

Is because you have another repository inside your main repository.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your subfolder (others). which is also contain the .git directory
so remove (delete) this folder. after that again {git add -> git commit -m -> git push origin} those commands are executed then your problem has been solved.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It occurs whenever by mistake you keep your init folder where it points out. In my case, I kept it in the Gallery folder by mistake and again initialized it in the same project during adding all the projects it showed this error.
[image: does not have a commit checked out]

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution when this occurs on rebase action

```
git rm --cached <submodule/path>
git add .
git rebase --continue
```

I hope somebody found this helpful

Answer (score -1):

I also had same issue and this is what i did

```
cd folder name
rm -rf git
then cd .. back to main folder
then git add .
```

it work, thank to all...

Answer (score -1):

In My case what happened was, I accidentally added git init in one of the sub folders . So i just deleted those .gits from sub folders.

**There should be only one .git file in your folder, there should not be any in any  subfolders.**

Removing them worked for me. and then Try again from beginning : 1.  `git init`    2. `git add -A` .......