# git error tracking a folder "Changes not staged for commit:"

Tags: git, github

I am working on an angular app inside a folder with a git repository connected to github.  Everytime I do a git commit, I get the following message that the main folder is not staged for commit:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   parcelFrontEnd (modified content)
```

parcelFrontEnd is the name of the angular-app folder, inside the folder with the git repository, so all the "meat" is inside the parcelFrontEnd folder.

I'm not sure why this is happening.

I have done:

```
git add .

git commit -m "....."

git push -u origin master
```

but it keeps giving me the message of:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   parcelFrontEnd (modified content)

no changes added to commit
```

I have even tried directly adding the folder with "git add parcelFrontEnd" and it still didn't work.

It is not an empty folder, there are plenty of files inside of it.

All the solutions I have read say to do "git add ." to add everything, but I have done that many times and I still keep getting the same error.

Below are the contents of my terminal window:

---

```
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
(base) Admins-MacBook-Pro:Parcel-Forwarding-Platforms admin$ git add .
(base) Admins-MacBook-Pro:Parcel-Forwarding-Platforms admin$ git commit -m "getting error about changes"
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   parcelFrontEnd (modified content)

no changes added to commit
(base) Admins-MacBook-Pro:Parcel-Forwarding-Platforms admin$ git add .
(base) Admins-MacBook-Pro:Parcel-Forwarding-Platforms admin$ git commit -m "what is going on"
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   parcelFrontEnd (modified content)

no changes added to commit
(base) Admins-MacBook-Pro:Parcel-Forwarding-Platforms admin$ git add parcelFrontEnd
(base) Admins-MacBook-Pro:Parcel-Forwarding-Platforms admin$ git commit -m "parcelFrontEnd edited"
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   parcelFrontEnd (modified content)

no changes added to commit
(base) Admins-MacBook-Pro:Parcel-Forwarding-Platforms admin$ git stash list
(base) Admins-MacBook-Pro:Parcel-Forwarding-Platforms admin$ git add .
(base) Admins-MacBook-Pro:Parcel-Forwarding-Platforms admin$ git commit -a "commiting before updating angular"
fatal: Paths with -a does not make sense.
(base) Admins-MacBook-Pro:Parcel-Forwarding-Platforms admin$ git stash
No local changes to save
(base) Admins-MacBook-Pro:Parcel-Forwarding-Platforms admin$ git add .
(base) Admins-MacBook-Pro:Parcel-Forwarding-Platforms admin$ git commit -m "typo"
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   parcelFrontEnd (modified content)

no changes added to commit
(base) Admins-MacBook-Pro:Parcel-Forwarding-Platforms admin$ git add .
(base) Admins-MacBook-Pro:Parcel-Forwarding-Platforms admin$ git commit -m "test"
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   parcelFrontEnd (modified content)

no changes added to commit
(base) Admins-MacBook-Pro:Parcel-Forwarding-Platforms admin$ git add parcelFrontEnd
(base) Admins-MacBook-Pro:Parcel-Forwarding-Platforms admin$ git commit -m "having  trouble"
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   parcelFrontEnd (modified content)

no changes added to commit
(base) Admins-MacBook-Pro:Parcel-Forwarding-Platforms admin$
```

Comment: Have you tried `commit` with the `-a` (`-all`) flag?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [github changes not staged for commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721624/github-changes-not-staged-for-commit)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Changes+not+staged+for+commit+modified+content

Comment: yeah I tried the "-all" flag.  I've tried a few different ways to "add everything" and it always gives me the same answer of "changes not staged for commit".

Comment: This is a submodule. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/58959998/1256452 and also phd's link.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

I'm not exactly sure what the problem was.  There might have been another git repository inside the sub-folder, meaning I had a git repository nested inside my main repository, which is called a "submodule".

I opened the sub-folder, looked around for hidden files, found some files with a .git extension and deleted them.

This might have fixed the problem if I had went a bit further, but I decided just to delete the local repo and the github repo and remake both.  I had only made just two small commits anyway.