# warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .vscode/launch.json

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, configuration

I have a .net core application with reactjs. And I am using visual studio code And I want to do a git push.

But then I get this warning:

```
> git add -A -- .
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .vscode/launch.json.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in ReactActivities/.gitignore.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
error: 'ReactActivities/API/' does not have a commit checked out
fatal: adding files failed
```

this is my launch.json file:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [        
        {
            // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
            // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
            // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/ReactActivities/API/bin/Debug/net5.0/API.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/ReactActivities/API",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            // Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

So I can't commit now. How to get rid of this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have just created an empty repository, so what you have to do is to create a initial commit in your repository.

Your error isn't the " LF will be replaced by CRLF".

Your error is "'ReactActivities/API/' does not have a commit checked out".

Check out this [git submodule add error: does not have a commit checked out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799562/git-submodule-add-error-does-not-have-a-commit-checked-out)

Comment: Ah, yes, that was the case. Thank you