# Trying to add an already cloned repo as a submodule gives error 'does not have a commit checked out'

Tags: git, git-submodules

Basically I have a repo where I cloned another repo. And now I want to add that sub-repo as a submodule of the parent repo but when I do `git submodule add http://sub-repo path-to-sub-repo` on the parent repo it gives me this error.

```
fatal: '/path-to-sub-repo' does not have a commit checked out
```

I suppose that this means that the sub repo has pending commits but no. Neither the parent repo nor the sub repo have pending commits or untracked files.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56799562/git-submodule-add-error-does-not-have-a-commit-checked-out) is a similar question but the answer is to make a new repo which is not what I want.

Answer (score -1):

I was using `~` in the path to the sub-repo

```
git submodule add https://sub-repo ~/path-to-sub-repo
```

I removed it and now it works fine.

```
git submodule add https://sub-repo path-to-sub-repo
```