# Error with git: " already exists and is not a valid git repo"

Tags: git, github, oauth

It is seying that I cannot do this:

```
 git submodule add -f git@github.com:thephpleague/oauth2-server.git libs/OAuth/functions
```

Because of this:

**'libs/OAuth/functions'** already exists and is not a valid **git repo**

I just don't get it. It does not exists anywhere. Is there another **git config file** hidden on my computer that I don't know of or something? I tried deleting **.git** and **pulling** everything again that did not do anything. Any ideas?

I also tried this:

```
git ls-files --stage functions
```

When I was inside of libs/OAuth and I got nothing.

Then I tried this:

```
sudo git rm --cached functions
```

I got this error:

```
fatal: pathspec 'functions' did not match any files
```

I also tried this:

```
sudo git rm -r --cached functions
```

And got the same previous error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if the folder doesn't exist, check the index status:

```
cd libs/OAuth
git ls-files -- functions
```

If there is an entry registered in the index, you will need to remove it before being able to add your subrepos as a submodule.
(as explained in "[Issue with adding common code as git submodule: “already exists in the index”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12902857/6309)")

All this assumes that you are at the root folder of a currently cloned repo, which will act as the parent repo of any submodule you would declare.

Comment: I did your command and I did not get anything. Then I tried to add the module again but did not work. I am getting the same error.

Comment: @jnbdz are you in a git repo when you are doing this command?

Comment: Yes. I am at the root of it when I try to add the submodule.

Comment: @jnbdz can you try, just for testing, to add the submodule in a different path? (try it in a clone of your actual repo, that way, you don't touch your existing repo)

Answer (score 18):

In case someone else had a similar case as mine and was struggling with this as I was because of a stupid reason:

Check if for any reason the file doesn't already exists (I had a failed git subomdule add previously)

So in the context of the question rm the file:

```
rm -rf libs/OAuth/functions
```

And then try to re add

Answer (score 4):

If you have tried and failed to add a submodule multiple times, this might cause errors when trying to add it correctly.

**Firstly**, ensure that the dir you are adding the submodule to does not exits.
**Secondly**, check your .git dir.
I had multiple dirs left in .git/modules/ that were causing issues.

After deleting these i were able to add the submodule to the specified dir as expexted.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens to me when I want to change the location of the submodule from X to Y

So what I do is:

1. Manually edit the project's `.gitmodules` with the new paths I want
2. Removing the directory manually with `rm -rf`
3. Running the following commands:

```
git submodule update
```

Then it re-read the configuration and sync the new directories

If you just want to completely remove the submodule then you need to remove the block of the submodule found in `.git/config`