# How to create submodule in existing repo

Tags: git, powershell, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm beginner to git & I have the following folder structure for new project, so what I did is I went to visual studio and I made empty project it  has this folder structure:

```
project: (Repo) 
folder1 (sub1)
folder2 (sub2)
```

I'm using git locally.
I created a repo for project using sourcetree,
now I cannot add any submodule, I don't know why.

In powershell whenever I try:

```
PS E:\Projects\Project> git submodule add ./sub1
```

I get the following error:

```
sub1 already exists in the index
```

then I decided to remove sub1 using `git rm -r sub1`,and add it again, then when I tried to add it again using `git submodule add` again, I received this new error:

```
sub1 already exists and is not a valid git repo
```

So what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with adding common code as git submodule: "already exists in the index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898278/issue-with-adding-common-code-as-git-submodule-already-exists-in-the-index)

Comment: its not i already seen it and before i make this topic and this is where i used git rm -r but after using it it showed new error as explained in my topic

Comment: Have you used --cached?

Comment: Yeah the problem was that i should have made the submodule git before adding it as submodule i thought adding submodule makes it git.. when i made new project it solved it

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[Adding a submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) means cloning another git repo inside an existing one and keep a reference to it.

In your case, you did not specify which repo you want to add:

```
git submodule add -- /url/of/sub1/repo sub1
```

---

if `sub1` or `sub2` are not supposed to be git repos of their own, but simple sub-folder of the main repo folder, then you do not need `git submodule add` command.
Simply add files in `sub1` and `sub2`, and you will be able to `git add` and `git commit` them.
No submodule involved.

Comment: they should be two different git repos

Comment: @ma1169 then the first part of my answer stands. You need to have remote repos for those subfolders.

Comment: can you explain this part  /url/if/sub1/repo sub1? so the url is the directory location..
what is /if/ and shouldn't it be url/if/repo/sub1 sub1??

Comment: @ma1169 I meant /of/ not /if/. And you need a remote url to clone to sub1. That is what ` /url/of/sub1/repo` is. For instance: `https://github.com/<user>/<arepo>`

Comment: @VonC if the `sub1` already exists? Because my Docker file is in the `sub1` directory

Comment: @MianAsbatAhmad It is best to ask a separate question to better understand your specific issue.

Answer (score 34):

You simply need to be in your root folder and then add the submodule folder.

```
git submodule add <url>
```

Now when you clone the project you simply need to init and update the submodule

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Git 1.8.2 features a new option --remote

```
git submodule update --remote --merge
```

will fetch the latest changes from upstream in each submodule, merge them in, and check out the latest revision of the submodule. As [the docs][1] put it:

> ***`--remote`***
>
> This option is only valid for the update command. Instead of using the superproject’s recorded SHA-1 to update the submodule, use the status of the submodule’s remote-tracking branch.

This is equivalent to running git pull in each submodule.

Comment: What i'm saying using git submodule add <url> causing the error i mentioned thanks.

Comment: You could also simply `git clone --recursive` instead of doing `git submodule init` and `git submodule update`