# Is there a way to split a multi-module Maven project into different Git repositories?

Tags: git, maven, pom.xml, dependency-management

I am currently developing two products. One of them is an open-source library that I want to provide free to the public. However, another product is paid and closed source but uses the library as a dependency. The two projects are in the same Maven project, (but just different submodules of a parent project). Currently, I have a Git repository housing both, but I want to house the library and the paid product separately, while still conserving that they are part of the same maven project. Would there be any great way to achieve this? (I know that I could create another separate Git repo with a separate Maven project, however, I want to allow it so I can build both projects when I use `mvn package` and write code on both sides very efficiently).

Comment: Separate the open source part into a separate repository (git) and build it separately. Use it as a usual dependency in your closed source project. Easiest way...

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> I know that I could create another separate Git repo with a separate Maven project

and, as suggested by @khmarbaise [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66067090/is-there-a-way-to-split-a-multi-module-maven-project-into-different-git-reposito#comment116811905_66067090), the easiest way would be to spin the open source component off into its own repo and use it like any other dependency.

> I want to allow it so I can build both projects when I use mvn package

If this is a priority, you can continue to treat the separate project as a Maven module of the closed-source project. Either refer to the checkout using something like `<module>../clone-directory-for-open-source-module</module>`, or [add it as a Git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534766/how-to-create-submodule-in-existing-repo).

You'll need to make sure that module builds on its own, as well as in the combined project, and your release process may be more complicated.

> write code on both sides very efficiently

One risk of tightly-coupled development is that you'll make changes in the open source component that don't make sense in isolation. This may or may not be an issue depending on the level of third-party contribution to that library.