# The GitHub submodule was not properly initialized with a .gitmodules

Tags: git, twitter-bootstrap, github, twitter-bootstrap-3, git-submodules

I have an error message on **GitHub** :

> Your site is having problems building: The submodule `bootstrap-touch-carousel` was not properly initialized with a `.gitmodules` file. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-missing-submodule.

Bacause of this error I can't see my site's URL.
It happened after I tried to include to my project bootstrap-touch-carousel: Add as Bootstrap git submodule 
`git submodule add git://github.com/ixisio/bootstrap-touch-carousel.git /vendor/your-sm`
It didn't work, so after that I locally added files.
But I can't fix this problem.
Help, please!
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git submodules in .gitmodules not initialized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441904/git-submodules-in-gitmodules-not-initialized)

Comment: @DimaSan after `git submodule add` it outputs `git: 'bootstrap-touch-carousel' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Comment: To add a new submodule you use the `git submodule add` command with the absolute or relative URL of the project you would like to start tracking (e.g., `git submodule add https://github.com/chaconinc/DbConnector`). More info can be found here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: @DimaSan Thank You! I'll try it!

Comment: @DimaSan After adding `$ git submodule add git://github.com/ixisio/bootstrap-touch-carousel.git /vendor/your-sm`
Outputs: `The following path is ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
/vendor/your-sm
Use -f if you really want to add it.` I use ` $ -f` But :
`bash: -f: command not found`

Comment: though the folder "bootstrap-touch-carousel" was created

Comment: after ` $ git submodule add http://ixisio.github.io/bootstrap-touch-carousel` outputs: `'bootstrap-touch-carousel' already exists in the index`

Comment: Check for this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898278/issue-with-adding-common-code-as-git-submodule-already-exists-in-the-index it may bereally helpful.