# Added wrong git submodule and cannot change its origin

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have added a new submodule to my git super-project:

```
git submodule add wrong-url project-directory
```

It was a wrong project, therefore I have removed it:

```
git submodule deinit -f project-directory
```

I tried to add it using the right url:

```
git submodule add right-url project-directory
```

Unfortunately it genrates an error: `already exists in the index`.

I found this to resolve the issue:
[Issue with adding common code as git submodule: "already exists in the index"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898278/issue-with-adding-common-code-as-git-submodule-already-exists-in-the-index?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Therefore, I run these commands:

```
git rm --cached project-directory
git rm -r --cached project-directory
```

However, as it is stated [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898278/issue-with-adding-common-code-as-git-submodule-already-exists-in-the-index?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#comment17486498_12902857), I get the error message `project-directory already exists and is not a valid git repo`. Thus I have deleted the `project-directory`, and the `project-directory` is added successfully.

The problem is the contents are linked to the `wrong-url`.

I have edited the `.gitmodules` (in which the url was wrong) and the result was the same.

I have also changed the remote url using `git remote rm origin` and added the correct url using `git remote add right-url`, but it doesn help.

I am curious where this wrong-remote-url is stored, and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It was a wrong project, therefore I have removed it:
>
> ```
> git submodule deinit -f project-directory
> ```

That will remove the entry from `.git/config` and clear the project-directory contents.

However, the entry in `.gitmodules` file is still intact. To get rid of it, simply delete the now empty directory from git and it will automatically clear that entry:

```
git rm -f project-directory
```

And finally, you ought to delete the actual git directory of the submodule, located in `.git/modules`:

```
rm -rf .git/modules/project-directory
```

That's it, no traces of the submodule should exist and you can add the correct one.

Comment: In addition to run `rm -rf .git/modules/project-directory`, I have removed the entry manually from `.gitmodules`. Then it is added successfully.