# Git, one remote is a subproject of the local version

Tags: git, github

I have a project (`pipeline`) that is also included as a part of a larger project (`aws_pipeline`). For both I have two different `github` accounts set up. I want to work on the `pipeline` project from within the `aws_pipeline` and then push it to the `pipeline` `git` account. Could anyone describe a `step-by-step` procedure of how to do basic push to the `pipeline` remote (from within `aws_pipeline)`? I added `pipeline` remote and can see it now when I do `git branch -a` in `aws_pipeline`. Now I need to somehow add some files that I modify, commit and push without pushing anything else in the large `aws_pipeline`. Pretty much I want a subfolder of the `aws_pipeline` to work as a separate `git` project attached to `pipeline`. I need the separation but want to have also synchronization of the `pipeline` between itself and the `aws_pipeline`. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> Update

To clarify more. I want to find a way to merge two folders instead of `deleting - add submodule` set of actions described here: [Issue with adding common code as git submodule: "already exists in the index"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898278/issue-with-adding-common-code-as-git-submodule-already-exists-in-the-index/14815959)

> Update

I solved it in my case by removing the folder, adding git submodule, then manually copy-pasting the modified files into the submodule. It does seem though too clumsy way of resolving this issue. If anyone has a better solution, would be awesome to see.

Comment: Did you have a look at git submodules ?

Comment: No, I honestly have no idea of how it should be handled. Going to look at it.

Comment: Can you clone the pipeline remote somewhere else and move the content of your subfolder into it so you can have the changes. Then do the git submodule add ?

Comment: Maybe, will see

Comment: No, I actually want to merge them, not just copy to different place - remove - add submodule - copy back... That just does not seem right

Comment: It was just a suggestion to get started with the submodule if you have work left in the pipeline directory. Otherwise, just remove and add the submodule, it should work fine

Comment: I am not sure how to actually do that. I have a folder that is named `pipeline`, but when I try running `git submodule add https:{...}/remote-pipeline pipeline`, it writes me that the index is already present. Its obvious why it gives this error, but not so obvious how to resolve this issue by merge two code bases.

Comment: There are sort of solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898278/issue-with-adding-common-code-as-git-submodule-already-exists-in-the-index/14815959 The only difference that I want to have is to actually be able to merge two folders (local and remote that I am adding as a `submodule`). Maybe there is just no functionality in git for this case, not sure.