# I can't push anymore to a github submodule using Hugo theme

Tags: github, git-submodules, hugo

My blog is hosted at `github.io` and it uses Hugo's "m10c" theme. The blog was working fine until today, when I tried to write two posts. I could post the first one, but, when I tried the second one, I could not `push` to the submodule in `main branch`. That was the error message:

```
error: src refspec main does not match any
```

So, I've investigate the `public` directory with:

```
git remote -v
```

And the result doesn't show the submodule repo (`igordeo-costa.github.io`), but only the repos where I maintain my static files. That was the command line and the error:

```
igor@skynet:.../public$ git push origin main
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/igordeo-costa/meuHugo.git'

igor@skynet:.../public$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/igordeo-costa/meuHugo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/igordeo-costa/meuHugo.git (push)
igor@skynet:/home/dados/MeuBLog/meuHugo/igorcosta/public$
```

I don't know what is happening here.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If it's not prviate, can you share with us the url of your repository? That might make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @larsks I think it must be https://github.com/igordeo-costa/igordeo-costa.github.io due to the name! I'd be quick to suspect using submodule is at fault, though it [is supported](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/using-submodules-with-github-pages)

Comment: Also, what command resulted in the `error: src refspec main does not
match any` error? You said you received the error when trying to
commit, but that error message is generally associated with a `push`
operation...

Comment: My mistake! In fact I received that message when I tried to `push` to the `main branch`, that is, the one who is a submodule for the `public` directory.

Comment: I've edit the question with the purpose of making myself clear.

Answer (score 1):

After giving it a few tries, I could finally solve the question with the help I found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898278/issue-with-adding-common-code-as-git-submodule-already-exists-in-the-index/14815959).

First of all, I cleaned up the cache for the public path:

```
igor@skynet:.../igorcosta$ git rm -r --cached public
```

Then, I forced a new submodule with:

```
igor@skynet:.../igorcosta$ sudo git submodule add --force https://github.com/igordeo-costa/igordeo-costa.github.io.git public
Adding existing repo at 'igorcosta/public' to the index
```

At that point, I thought that the problem had already been solved. So, I ran the Hugo's code to create the public directory:

```
igor@skynet:.../igorcosta$ sudo hugo -t "m10c"
```

The command `git remote -v` showed me the correct path to the submodule:

```
igor@skynet:/home/dados/MeuBLog/meuHugo/igorcosta/public$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/igordeo-costa/igordeo-costa.github.io.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/igordeo-costa/igordeo-costa.github.io.git (push)
```

Finally, I ran the `add`, `commit` and `push` to the submodule `main branch` and then it worked perfectly!

Thank you, guys, for the help!